# How to make this code working django url path

Tags: python, django, urlconf

My code is not working, and I am not sure why.
I have the problem with hours_ahead function.
Here is urlpatterns path('time/plus/(\d{1,2})/', hours_ahead),
And I imported hours_ahead too

[image: My code]

Comment: could you elaborate a bit what "my code is not working" means? What is the issue you are experiencing?

Comment: It means that  when i go to  http://127.0.0.1:8000/time/plus/3/   it shows me page not found. And the thing is that i wanted to make dynamic code that can show time and in the same time i dont need to make new paths for every hour it resets. I think that the problem is in this part of the code path('time/plus/(\d{1,2})/', hours_ahead), I want this url to me dynamic

Comment: You can use `path('time/plus/<int:offset>/', hours_ahead)`

Comment: what version of django are you using? It appears like your url path contains a regex but path no longer supports regexs since [version 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#using-regular-expressions). So you'd need to use `re_path('time/plus/(\d{1,2})/')` instead.

Comment: Sir,
Can you explain  me <int:offset> this part of the code, or give me some resource to study it a little?

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments with the *code sample* button (`{}`).

Answer (score 1):

One of these may work

In your urls.py add something like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('hours/<int:offset>/', hours_ahead)
]
```

the "int:offset" is a way of saying what is the parameter you are going to receive and the type.

in settings.py add:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [ # careful to not create another INSTALLED_APPS,add the app to the list! 
# ...
'playground'
```

]

Also, I got this error on my terminal:

```
CommandError: 'playgrounds' conflicts with the name of an existing Python module and cannot be used as an app name. Please try another name.
```

I could not run the code until I created and app with another name.